# Update a relation in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models.

### fb_page.rb

```
has_one :fb_page_template, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fb_page_template, :allow_destroy => false
```

### fb_page_template.rb

```
belongs_to :fb_page
has_many :subscriptions
```

Active admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register FbPage do
  form title: 'Facebook page form' do |f|
    f.has_many :fb_page_template, new_record: false, allow_destroy: false do |k|
        k.input :subscribed
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I try to update the form, it tries to delete subscriptions and fb_page_template as well.

All I want is to update the value of `subscribed` which is  in `fb_page_template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're missing couple things here:

- You need to allow `accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions, :allow_destroy => false` in your `fb_page_template.rb`
- You need to allow all nested attributes in ActiveAdmin too.
- You need to nest the forms.

This is what I have in my `fb_pages.rb` for ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register FbPage do
  permit_params :attribute_name_for_fb_page, 
                fb_page_template_attributes: [
                  :id, :fb_page_id, :attribute_name_for_fb_page_template,
                  subscriptions_attributes: [
                    :subscribed,
                    :fb_page_template_id
                  ]
                ]

  form title: "Facebook page form" do |f|
    f.inputs do 
      f.input :attribute_name_for_fb_page 

      f.has_many :fb_page_template, allow_destroy: false do |t|
        t.input :attribute_name_for_fb_page_template

        t.has_many :subscriptions do |s|  
          s.input :subscribed, as: :boolean
        end
      end
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

And this is what I have in the `fb_page_template.rb`

```
class FbPageTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fb_page
  has_many :subscriptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions, :allow_destroy => false
end
```

Hope this works for you.